# How to integrate a QR-code to access a module in my app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, qr-code

I'm working on a mobile app for Android that makes reservations. The way it works is that every employee will have a QR code designated and when the user scans the code it will take them to a reservation screen with said employee.

For what I've research QR codes work with URL. So I don't know if there's a way to create a URL that goes to the app or how could this work.

I'm using React Native and the app already has a QR code scanner, with this library https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner

The way I see it is that it should work something like how Instagram sends you to a user profile with the Name tag. https://thepreviewapp.com/use-instagram-name-tag-qr-code-everything-need-know/

Comment: if I correctly understand you need to know about deep-linking.maybe this links can help you https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e  and  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking